# Check Boxes, Store in Array and utilize switch statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, switch-statement

Thank you in advance to anyone who answers this.

**What I need help on:**
How to display the number of checkboxes selected by automatically updated them?For example: If I select 1 check box from SECTION A it will display 1 from SECTION A. If I select another box it will display 2 from SECTION A automatically, but it will also subtract the value if the check box is unselected. Kind of like a tally

Again, thank you for helping me and for your time.

```
    var infoArray=new Array();

function userSelection(userInput)
{
  var itemName = userInput.name;
  var itemName2 = userInput.value;

 switch(itemName)
 {
  case "sectionR":
 {
  switch(itemName2)
 {
  case "repair car":
       infoArray[0]=1;
  break;

  case "wood work":
       infoArray[0]=1;
  break;

  case "explore forest":
       infoArray[0]=1;
  //end of case "sectionR"
 }
  //end of sub switch
 }
  break;

   case "sectionA":
 {
  switch(itemName2)
 {
  case "clothing design":
       infoArray[1]=1;
  break;

  case "public singing":
       infoArray[1]=1;
  break;

  case "decorate":
       infoArray[1]=1;
  //end of sub switch
 }
 // end of case sectionA
 }
 //end of main switch
 }  
    var userOutput=new Array();
   for(var i=0; i<itemName.length; i++)
   {
      userOutput.push(itemName[i].checked);
   }

document.getElementById("selectionTotal").innerHTML = "R SECTION" + "&nbsp" + "," + "&nbspA SECTION" + "<br>" + 
infoArray;

 //end of userSelection() 
}
```

Comment: Maybe try looking at `checked` attribute when dealing with checkbox or radio inputs [w3school link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the first two lines of your function:

```
var userInput = document.getElementsByName('sectionR');
var userOutput = document.getElementsByName('sectionR').value;
```

First of all, it could be written simpler and more elegant:

```
var userInput = document.getElementsByName('sectionR');
var userOutput = userInput.value;
```

But that would still contain the same error. `document.getElementsByName("sectionR")` returns an array with all elements with the name "sectionR". So you can't get a value from the array. You have to iterate through the elements:

```
var userOutput = []; // or var userOutput = new Array();
for (var i=0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    userOutput.push(userInput[i].value);
}
```

Now you have the values for all elements with the name "sectionR" in your array `userOutput` and can use them later.

Also a notice on your for-loop. You declare `x=0` without the keyword `var`. This makes the variable `x` visible in the global scope. It can lead to some unexpected behaviour if your code is longer and you use avariable with the same name somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you. I reworded the question a bit if you have the time would you mind re-reviewing it?

Comment: @ClintonVlasak Unfortunately you messed the things now even more. Tomorrow I'll check it again as it is late now here in Europe and I need some rest. Please be patient until then.

Comment: Lol, thank you for being straight forward. If you do get the time to look at my code, I revised it almost completely. I got it to display the individual values for each index which is wonderful. However, do you know how to display the out put so it displays the number of checkboxes checked?